# How to save the registration information that is spread across several pages?

Tags: php, forms, registration

I have this registration process for a website, and I'm trying to save all the information that spans across several web pages.  How do i do that?  Because the $_POST field only keeps information of the last form that was submitted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few options:

- Use session variables
- Use cookies
- Store the answers in a seperate (pre-registration) table in your database
- Use POST variables. (You would need to use hidden fields, whose values would contain the data from all previous pages).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [sessions](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) for this.

At the top of each page, you run [`session_start()`](http://ca.php.net/session_start) before anything else. This will load any existing session, or start a new one if none exists.

From there, you can store information into the [`$_SESSION` superglobal array](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php). This array will be populated automatically by PHP using the data stored in it on previous pages when you call `session_start()` on a new page.